# Database design for metro train route stations and timing

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many

I am making a city metro train app, and for that, I need some advice from you all experts on how to design a database for the following requirements.

- The metro has multiple lines (see table), and each station is associated with its respective line.
- By selecting two stations, the system should display all stations
  between routes. That includes the total number of stations, total distance, and total time.
- If the route has multiple lines than at the point where the line changes, I want to indicate something like (change line)
- Train schedule and timing on each station by weekdays. So the user can see all trains for the stations or train by timings

I have created the following tables now stuck how I can make a timetable that associates with the train as well as each station, how I can query to get all list of stations on the route with Line change indication.

## Create Table Query

> Please ignore all NOT NULL as I still have to finalize it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff
(
    id         INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username   VARCHAR(55) UNIQUE  NOT NULL,
    password   VARCHAR(100)        NOT NULL,
    email      VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    phone      INT(12) UNIQUE      NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP           NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP                    DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX staff_index (username, email, phone)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS route_lines
(
    id   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    INDEX route_index (name)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stations
(
    id         INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name       VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    code       CHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    line_id    INT UNSIGNED    NOT NULL,
    created_by INT UNSIGNED    NOT NULL,
    updated_by INT UNSIGNED             DEFAULT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP                DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX station_index (name, code),
    CONSTRAINT station_route_line FOREIGN KEY (line_id) REFERENCES route_lines (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routes
(
    id     INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    number INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    INDEX route_index (number)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS route_stations
(
    id              INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    route_id        INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    station_id      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    next_station_id INT UNSIGNED          DEFAULT NULL,
    station_order   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    line_id         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    distance        FLOAT        NOT NULL,
    time            TIME         NOT NULL,
    INDEX route_stations_index (station_id),
    CONSTRAINT route_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (route_id) REFERENCES routes (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT station_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (station_id) REFERENCES stations (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT next_station_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (next_station_id) REFERENCES stations (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories
(
    id   INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    slug VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    INDEX cat_index (name)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trains
(
    id             INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name           VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    number         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    origin_id      INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    destination_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    category_id    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    route_id       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    created_by     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    updated_by     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    created_at     TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at     TIMESTAMP             DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX train_index (name, number),
    CONSTRAINT train_cat_fk FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT train_origin_fk FOREIGN KEY (origin_id) REFERENCES stations (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT train_destination_fk FOREIGN KEY (destination_id) REFERENCES stations (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT train_route_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (route_id) REFERENCES routes (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

## Diagram

[image]

> I have also added some placeholder data for a visual demonstration.

## Routes

[image]

## Route Lines

[image]

## Stations

[image]

## Route Stations

[image]

## Categories

[image]

## Trains

[image]

## Questions

1. how I can query to get all list of stations on the route with Line
   change indication.
2. How to create a train time table and schedule that associate to each station.

Comment: @Akina 1.how I can query to get all list of stations on the route with Line change indication. 2. How to create a train time table and schedule that associate to each station.

Comment: 1) You have stations on the route. If you have 2 stations with the same name (or code?) and different line_id - it is line change, mark it. 2) Your scheme do not store such data.

Comment: @Akina 1) Do you mean I will have to make a duplicate entry for Station that has two lines? 2) Yes I do not have but I need some hint to make it

Comment: 1) Of course. Or maybe you know the way to place 2 values about 2 different line ids into one stations.line_id field? 2) No way, you must enter/store all train schedules, arrivals and departures for each station on each separate schedule. The train may pass the station or stay longer than usual.

Comment: @Akina cool.. thanks that will help me a lot to start up on it.

Comment: Since stations is on multiple lines, do not include `line_id` in `stations`.  Etc.

Comment: @RickJames so where and how I should define `line_id` for each station/

Comment: A "line" would be 2 tables:  One describing the basic info about the line (name, etc); the other listing each station (one per row), and possibly this would have an ordering column.  This last table would include `station_id` more than once if more than one `line` goes through that station.